# Array.some() is always false even if the condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a function that gets an array of strings representing dates and then checking if a given date is in the array. However, I am always getting `false` even if the condition is met.

Here is a minimal code:

```js
let dates = ['2020-06-29', '2020-07-13'];
dates = dates.map(some_day => new Date(some_day));
const someDay = new Date(2020, 5, 29);
console.log(dates.some(some_day => some_day.getTime() === someDay.getTime()));
```

**Edit 1: (Still not working but I am improving the code)**

```js
let dates = ['2020-06-29', '2020-07-13'];
dates = dates.map(some_day => new Date(some_day));
let someDay = new Date(2020, 5, 29);
const date_string = `${someDay.getFullYear()}-${someDay.getMonth() + 1}-${someDay.getDate()}`;
someDay = new Date(date_string);
console.log(dates.some(some_day => some_day.getTime() === someDay.getTime()));
```

Comment: Time will be different. console.log() and you will see

Comment: Passing a date string and passing individual date components results in different behaviour, specifically regarding timezones. Since the timezone is different, the `getTime()` values are different, so the results don't match.

Comment: try setting new date from string. `someDay = new Date('2020-06-29')`

Comment: you don't have any date which would match a date in the array...

Comment: `const someDay = new Date(2020, 5, 29);
  console.log(dates.some(some_day => {
  console.log(some_day.toLocaleTimeString(), someDay.toLocaleTimeString())
  return some_day.getTime() === someDay.getTime()
}));`

Comment: I agree with @NiettheDarkAbsol and I also noted that in the example you posted one date is in may and the other one in june, so they are pretty different :)

Comment: Guys, months in JS starts with 0 as January.

Comment: There's no equal dates. TimeZones may different. However, It's better to use something like ```moment.js``` to prevent mistakes.

Comment: @PedroLima that's not relevant here. The problem is that `new Date('2020-06-29') !== new Date(2020, 5, 29)` because the *time* portion is different. Yes, the month will be the same and *maybe* the date (depending on local timezone) but the whole issue is that the two dates are handled differently with regards to assumed timezone.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm referring to the multiple people saying there are no equal dates in the array. They are mistaking `new Date(2020, 5, 29)` as May.

Comment: @PedroLima they are saying that there aren't any equal *date objects*. It's a shorthand and all of them have explained that *the time is different*. Which is why the `Date` constructor (shorthand - "date") yields different values.

Comment: @VLAZ, have you read the comment by Stockafisso? Plus, I'm pretty sure the comments that only state "there are no equal elements in the array" and have no further info committed the same mistake.

Comment: Avoid using strings to parse dates, they can produce different results in different browsers

Comment: @PedroLima OK, so that's *one* comment. Why not address it directly?

Comment: @VLAZ "Plus, I'm pretty sure the comments that only state "there are no equal elements in the array" and have no further info committed the same mistake."

Comment: @Lennholm the behaviour of the Date constructor wrt to the simplified ISO8601 strings is *very* well defined. If a browser is not respecting it, you likely have larger problems at hand. The browse is running non-compliant JavaScript.

Comment: @VLAZ From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date: *"Note: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse(), which works the same way) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies."*

Comment: @Lennholm I assure you that [the simplified ISO8601 format is quite well specced](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). If you find a browser does not respect it, then I strongly suggest not using that browser as it's not running standard compliant JavaScript. [Not even ES5 compliant](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2). You can check Annex E which lists the changes from ES3: "*15.9.4.2: **Date.parse** is now required to first attempt to parse its argument as an ISO format string.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of timezone difference, either manipulate timezoneoffset, or:

```
dates.some(some_day => 
  (
    (some_day.getFullYear() === someDay.getFullYear()) &&
    (some_day.getMonth() === someDay.getMonth()) &&
    (some_day.getDate() === someDay.getDate())
  )
)
```

Comment: Like others have suggested, I agree and think that instead of `const someDay = new Date(2020, 5, 29);` you should use `const someDay = new Date('2020-06-29');`.

Comment: Actually I am getting the `date` as an object of type `Date`. https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker#filter

Comment: There must be many.  If you don't use `Date` methods, you could stick to `String`.  To learn more about `Date`, I recommend: [Date - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: That's actually a really bad approach. It will only work in eastern timezones. In western timezones `new Date('2020-06-29')` will become jun 28th and `.getDate` will return 28.

Comment: @PedroLima How to solve the problem that you have stated?

Comment: go back and forth with UTC/JSON?

Comment: `let dates = ['2020-06-29', '2020-07-13'];
const someDay = '2020-06-29';
console.log(dates.some(some_day => 
  some_day==domeDay
));`

Comment: @Ambitions This answer implies your problem can be solved by changing the way you compare the dates, but your problem is with the creation, not the comparison. Avoid using strings to create dates unless it is in a full ISO date format.`.getTime()` is a valid way of comparing dates, so no changes need to be done there.